# Different fixed effect models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I am stuck at understanding the difference between different types of fixed effect models. In particular, what is the difference between:

1. A two way fixed effect model in the form of $$y_{it} = \alpha_i + \gamma_t + \mathbf x_{it}^\top \beta + \epsilon_{it},$$ 
   where $\gamma_t$ is the time fixed effect and $\alpha_i$ the entity fixed effect. In the literature this is called two-way fixed effect most of the time.
2. A fixed effect model in the type of

$$y_{it} = \sigma_{it} + \mathbf x_{it}^\top \beta + \epsilon_{it},$$ where the time fixed effects and the entity fixed effects are combined in one estimator. That would mean you would have a time-entity dummy for each combination. Are there any paper regarding this kind of fixed effect model?

Some explanation would be really nice.

Thank you!

Comment: The terms fixed and random are used by different people (or the same people) at different times to mean different things. See: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2005/01/25/why_i_dont_use/

Comment: So, in the second case, when combining entity and time fixed effects, it is rather a random effects model? My question results from an excerpt in a paper, where it says:

Furthermore, country x 5-year fixed effects capture general, time-varying institutional and policy factors that can affect the shape of the yield curve...

Comment: what paper what page?

Comment: Working paper "The Importance of Sovereign Reference Rates for Corporate Debt Issuance: Mind the Gap" p. 15. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome Max! This is a quote from page 22 of the aforementioned [working paper](https://sites.insead.edu/facultyresearch/research/file.cfm?fid=64731). It appears they are referring to the *interaction* between country and year. Is your question specific to a single ‘entity-year’ fixed effect, and not the interaction between two separate fixed effects for entity and year?

Comment: Hi Tom! Oh, I am sorry, there might be different versions of this particular paper online, that is why I gave the wrong page number.

What I understand is the interaction between 2 seperate fixed effects for entity and year. That is, at least from my unterstanding, the common two-way-fixed effects approach. What I don't understand is the single entity-year fixed effect. I can't seem to find any source where I can read something about this approach. How will the result even look like? An entity-year dummy for each combination? Any insight into the entity-year fe approach would be helpful! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two way fixed effect model (TWFE)

$$y_{it} = \alpha_i + \gamma_t + \mathbf x_{it}^\top \beta + \epsilon_{it},$$

is treated in the seminal paper Abowd, Kramerz and Magolis (1999) *High Wage Workers and High Wage Firms*.

The model

$$y_{it} = \sigma_{it} + \mathbf x_{it}^\top \beta + \epsilon_{it},$$

cannot be estimated using within estimator under the standard fixed effect assumption that $\sigma_{it}$ is correlated with $\mathbf x_{it}$ because there is a fixed effect for each observation $(i,t)$ (this is completely analogously to allowing for individual fixed effects with only cross-section data $y_{i} = \mu_{i} + \mathbf x_{i}^\top \beta + \epsilon_{i}$).

Still in comparing the two models it is evident that the first model can be achieved by the restricting assumption that $\sigma_{it} = \alpha_i + \delta_t$. Restricting because the second model allows for individual specific time path $\sigma_{i,t_1},\sigma_{i,t_2},...,\sigma_{i,T}$ whereas the first model assumes the timepath $\delta_{t_1},\delta_{t_2},...,\delta_{T}$ is the same for all individuals.

In the working paper you cite the authors have data from 14 countries in the period 1991-2017 and they focus on what they refer to as "country-year-maturity bins".

Let the index $c=1,...,14$ be the country index and $t=1,...,27$ be the year index. Then for each country $c$ at time $t$ they have observations on a set of maturity bins $k=1,...,9$. Their number of observations should therefore be $C*T*K = 14*27*9$. The model may be written as

$$y_{kct} = \sigma_{ct} + x_{kct}^\top \beta + \epsilon_{kct}$$

so the fact that there are several maturity bins $k=1,..,K$ allows application of the within estimator. And the fact that the fixed effects for country $\alpha_c$ and time $\delta_t$ are interacted allows for a more general model where country specific timepaths are allowed.